# This tag breaks the site's [contract]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contract)

No usage guidance, applied hither and thither, only 318 mostly-zero-upvote questions.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No, and no.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   In the same way that programming is.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Absolutely not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No: it can be used in terms of blockchain or system interfaces, for example.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that we have [[tag:code-contracts]] and [[tag:design-by-contract]] for those questions about contracts that *are* on-topic and *do* need an appropriate tag. [[tag:code-contracts]] is about the .NET feature. I'm not sure what we're going to do about the C++20 feature. That was the first thing I thought of when I saw the tag name.

Comment: Nobody that is going to post a good answer is going to wonder what a question tagged [c++20][contract] might be about.  Anybody that has no clue really ought to take a look, that's a good way to learn about what is new.  Its a functional tag, don't kill it.

Comment: @CodyGray [tag:design-by-contracts] is nowhere near intuitive enough a name to be used for the kind of contracts they describe, if I'm reading it right (e.g. the kind of contracts that blockchain techs use)

Comment: @HansPassant most likely I think anyone unaware of the C++ feature would assume "contract" refers to a business contract and jump to a false conclusion about it being off topic before reading it.

Comment: @DanNeely: I don't think people close questions based entirely on their *tags* (even during burnination, we don't do that).

Comment: @DanNeely The issue isn't that people see **questions** tagged this way and assume they're off-topic, it's that people see [contract] and [assume they can ask about legal contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099259/contract-for-hosted-software)

Comment: Not a great example, @Mac. Back in 2009, people asked about [pretty much anything](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/), the existence of tags notwithstanding. I also think this idea that we need to "burninate" tags because people might get the wrong impression is extremely dangerous. I've made this point before about [[tag:python]] being a large, non-venomous snake, yet a completely appropriate tag. Everything here is interpreted *within the context of programming*. If you can't figure that out, well, that's why we have close votes.

Comment: There's also some design-by-contract libraries which already have their own tags, eg [spring-cloud-contract].

Comment: @CodyGray I never thought of that this way, I think contract needs a updated description and it will be good.